# Can we click images with camera preview overlay?

Tags: android, camera, overlay

I have an overlay in the camera preview. I just want the clicked images to be saved with that overlay. Is it possible?

Comment: Something is not clear in your question. Maybe you can provide a sketch of your desired layout. What are these "clicked images"? Objects detected in the camera preview? Or imageViews that are laid up on top of the camera preview?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code to use an overlay image on top of camera preview with surface holder. Hope it helps someone.

OK i got the solution.

```
Code:

package com.sailabs.photo;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
      private Camera camera = null;
      private SurfaceView cameraSurfaceView = null;
      private SurfaceHolder cameraSurfaceHolder = null;
      private boolean previewing = false;
      RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
      private Context myContext;
      private boolean cameraFront = false;
      public int glo = 0;
   // private TextView text = null;

      private Button capture = null;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
      {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
          myContext = this;
          getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
          requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
          getWindow().setFlags(
                  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        relativeLayout=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.containerImg);
        relativeLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        cameraSurfaceView = (SurfaceView)
                                           findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
        //  text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
      //  cameraSurfaceView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(640, 480));
        cameraSurfaceHolder = cameraSurfaceView.getHolder();
        cameraSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    //    cameraSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.
      //                                               SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);




        capture = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        capture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {   
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) 
          {
            /*  text.setText("1");
              try{
                  Thread.sleep(1000);

              }catch (Exception e)
              {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
              text.setText("2");
              try{
                  Thread.sleep(1000);

              }catch (Exception e)
              {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
              text.setText("3");
              try{
                  Thread.sleep(1000);

              }catch (Exception e)
              {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }*/


              CaptureThread captureThread = new CaptureThread();
              captureThread.start();


              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
        });
      }
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    private int findFrontFacingCamera() {
        int cameraId = -1;
        // Search for the front facing camera
        int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
            Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
            if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                cameraId = i;
                cameraFront = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return cameraId;
    }


    ShutterCallback cameraShutterCallback = new ShutterCallback()
      {  
        @Override
        public void onShutter() 
        {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub   
        }
      };

      PictureCallback cameraPictureCallbackRaw = new PictureCallback() 
      {  
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) 
        {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub   
        }
      };

      PictureCallback cameraPictureCallbackJpeg = new PictureCallback()
      {  
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) 
        {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub   
          Bitmap cameraBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray
                                                                      (data, 0, data.length);

         int   wid = cameraBitmap.getWidth();
         int  hgt = cameraBitmap.getHeight();

        //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), wid+""+hgt, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          Bitmap newImage = Bitmap.createBitmap
                                            (wid, hgt, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

          Canvas canvas = new Canvas(newImage);

          canvas.drawBitmap(cameraBitmap, 0f, 0f, null);

          Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mark3);
          drawable.setBounds(20, 30, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth()+20, drawable.getIntrinsicHeight()+30);
          drawable.draw(canvas);



          //File storagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/pics/");
         // storagePath.mkdirs();
            File mediaStorageDir = new File("/sdcard/", "pics");

          // File myImage = new File(storagePath, +".jpg");
            File myImage = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "pic" + glo + ".png");
            Log.d("naval", "File path :" + myImage);
            glo++;

          try
          {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(myImage);
            newImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);


            out.flush();
            out.close();
          }
          catch(FileNotFoundException e)
          {
            Log.d("In Saving File", e + "");    
          }
          catch(IOException e)
          {
            Log.d("In Saving File", e + "");
          }

          camera.startPreview();



         // newImage.recycle();
        //  newImage = null;

         // Intent intent = new Intent();
        //  intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        //  intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + myImage.getAbsolutePath()), "image/*");
        //  startActivity(intent);

        }
      };

      @Override
      public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, 
                                           int format, int width, int height) 
      {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(previewing)
        {
          camera.stopPreview();
          previewing = false;
        }
        try 
        {
          Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
         // parameters.setPreviewSize(640, 480);
         // parameters.setPictureSize(640, 480);
          if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
              camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

          }

         // parameters.setRotation(90);
          camera.setParameters(parameters);

          camera.setPreviewDisplay(cameraSurfaceHolder);
          camera.startPreview();
          previewing = true;
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();  
        }
      }

      @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
      @Override
      public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) 
      {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
        {
          camera = Camera.open(findFrontFacingCamera());
        }
        catch(RuntimeException e)
        {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Device camera  is not working properly, please try after sometime.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) 
      {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
        previewing = false;
      }

    class CaptureThread extends Thread {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            int count = 0;

            while (count < 30) {
                //  mFileName = mLocation + "/pic" + count + ".jpg";
                try {
                    Log.d("Naval","camera clicked");
                    camera.takePicture(cameraShutterCallback,
                                           cameraPictureCallbackRaw,
                                           cameraPictureCallbackJpeg);

                    //mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);

                    count++;


                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            glo = 0; // images will be save from 0 in pics folder
            try {
                // wait(5000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            createGif();


        }


        public void createGif() {

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            AnimatedGifEncoder encoder = new AnimatedGifEncoder();
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 6;

            encoder.setDelay(50);
            encoder.start(bos);
            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/storage/emulated/0/pics/pic" + i + ".png", options);
                Log.d("naval", "added image");

                encoder.addFrame(bMap);
                // encoder.setQuality(100);
            }
            encoder.finish();

            writeToFile(bos.toByteArray());

            try {
                Log.d("naval - lets sleep", "Turn again to click");
                Thread.sleep(5000);

                SocketServerThread sc = new SocketServerThread();
                sc.initialize();
                sc.start();


                //capture.performClick();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        }

        public void writeToFile(byte[] array) {
            try {
                String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/gif/gif.gif";
                FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(path);
                stream.write(array);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private class SocketServerThread extends Thread {

        int count = 0;
        String message = "";
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        // String message = "";
        static final int socketServerPORT = 4444;
        public String ip = getIpAddress();

        public SocketServerThread()throws IOException
        {
            // serverSocket

            Log.d("naval", " constructor thread");


        }
        public void initialize () {
            try {
                Log.d("naval", "Initialize socket");

                serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
                serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
                serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(6677));
            }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.1");


                // serverSocket = new ServerSocket(socketServerPORT);
                if(serverSocket == null)
                {
                    Log.d("naval", "ye to null hai bhai");

                }
                while (true) {
                    Log.d("naval","waiting for packet at port  and IP :"+ip+"a"+serverSocket.getInetAddress()+"b"+serverSocket.getLocalPort());
                    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    Log.d("naval", " packet get");
                    String encoding   = "";
                    /* receiving from client*/
                    try {
                        InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

                        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
                        String line;
                        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                            total.append(line);
                        }
                        Log.d("naval", total.toString());
                        message = total.toString();
                        if(message.equals("start")) {

                            try{
                                // r.close();
                                // inputStream.close();
                                serverSocket.close();
                                socket.close();

                            }catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {

                                    Log.d("naval","click performed");

                                    capture.performClick();

                                }
                            });
                            //
                            Log.d("naval","breaking while loop");
                            break;
                        }



                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        ioe.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    //socket.close();


                    Log.d("naval","closing socket");
                    count++;

                    //   message += "#" + count + " from "
                    //  + socket.getInetAddress() + ":"
                    //  + socket.getPort() + "\n";


                }
                //serverSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public String getIpAddress() {
            String ip = "";
            try {
                Enumeration<NetworkInterface> enumNetworkInterfaces = NetworkInterface
                        .getNetworkInterfaces();
                while (enumNetworkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
                    NetworkInterface networkInterface = enumNetworkInterfaces
                            .nextElement();
                    Enumeration<InetAddress> enumInetAddress = networkInterface
                            .getInetAddresses();
                    while (enumInetAddress.hasMoreElements()) {
                        InetAddress inetAddress = enumInetAddress
                                .nextElement();

                        if (inetAddress.isSiteLocalAddress()) {
                            ip += "Server running at : "
                                    + inetAddress.getHostAddress();
                        }
                    }
                }

            } catch (SocketException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                ip += "Something Wrong! " + e.toString() + "\n";
            }
            return ip;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the Layout XML file code too?